# Sort an array by a number in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$anArray = ['aValue (17)', 'anotherValue (5)', 'someData (3)']
```

How can I sort this array by the number in the brackets?

The result should look like that:

```
$anArray = ['someData (3)', 'anotherValue (5)', aValue (17)']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can solve your problem

```
$anArray = ['aValue (17)', 'anotherValue (5)', 'someData (3)'];

$anArray = sortMyArray($anArray);
function sortMyArray($arr){
    $keyValueArray = [];
    foreach ($arr as $element) {

        // ( position
        $start  = strpos($element, '(');
    
        // ) position
        $end    = strpos($element, ')', $start + 1);
        
        $length = $end - $start;
    
        // Get the number between parantheses
        $num = substr($element, $start + 1, $length - 1);
    
        // check if its a number
        if(is_numeric($num)){
            $keyValueArray[$num] = $element;
        }
    }
    
    // Sort the array by its keys
    ksort($keyValueArray);
    
    // reassign your array with sorted elements
    $arr = array_values($keyValueArray);
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number using regex and pass that into the sort compare function, like this:

```js
function numerical(str) {
    const pattern = /\(\d+\)/g;
    const matches = str.match(pattern); // e.g. ["(25)"]
    if (matches.length > 0) {
        return parseInt(matches[0].slice(1, -1));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$anArray = ['aValue (17)', 'anotherValue (5)', 'someData (3)']
$anArray.sort((x,y) => numerical(x)-numerical(y));
console.log($anArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this:

```
const $anArray = ['aValue (17)', 'anotherValue (5)', 'someData (3)'];
$anArray.sort((n1, n2) => {
  return n1.match(/(\d+)/)[0] - n2.match(/(\d+)/)[0]
})
console.log($anArray)
```